# Webserver on RaspberryPi is not reachable with DynDNS

Tags: docker, apache, raspberry-pi, webserver

I got a Docker Setup with an Apache Webserver on my RaspberryPi. I want to reach this webserver from the internet. So I got a domain and activated the dyndns to my fritz.box router.
But I only a Site not found error.

This is my docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3.4"

services:
  apache:
    restart: always
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    volumes:
      - /home/pi/reverse-proxy/:/etc/apache2
      - /home/pi/reverse-proxy/certificates/:/etc/ssl/ms/
    networks:
      - homeserver

  portainer:
    restart: always
    image: portainer/portainer-ce:latest
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
      - "9000:9000"
      - "9443:9443"
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
      - portainer_data:/data
    networks:
      - homeserver

networks:
  homeserver:
```

and this is the apache config:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
 ServerName stoelting-michael.de
 ProxyPreserveHost On 
 DocumentRoot /var/www/html
 ProxyPass /.well-known !
 ProxyPass / http://192.168.178.21:8080/
 ProxyPassReverse / http://192.168.178.21:8080/
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =stoelting-michael.de
RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
</VirtualHost>
```

If I call `http://192.168.178.21` the correct site pops up. So the apache works. But if I try the domain, it doesn't work.

The setup works a couple of days ago perfectly, but after I got a new Router all is a mess. I googled a lot about it and found something, that maybe the problem is IPv6. So I tried to add IPv6 to the docker setup and added this to the docker-compose.yml:

```
    enable_ipv6: true
    ipam:
      config:
        - subnet: 2001:db8:a::/64
          gateway: 2001:db8:a::1
```

and this to the docker/daemon.json:

```
{
  "ipv6": true,
  "fixed-cidr-v6": "fd00::/80",
  "experimental": true,
  "ip6tables": true
}
```

But this also didn't work.

Does some got an idea how I can fix or start to debug this?